# For loop strange behavior

Tags: for-loop, pine-script

I need to call a function **y** times and see if only 1 of those calls is true. I am trying to optimize my pinescript code using a for loop however the result always returns false.

This works (x is 1) but takes too much space if I need to call the function for example 100 times:

```
x = 0
if function(1) or function(2) or ... function(y)
    x := x + 1
```

This doesn't work (x is always 0):

```
x = 0
for i = 1 to y
    if x == 1
        break
    if function(i)
        x := x + 1
```

I tried this as well (x is always 0):

```
x = 0
x := for i = 1 to y
    if x == 1
        break
    if function(i)
        x := x + 1
        x
    x
```

This is the function that I am trying to run:

```
helper4function(cond) => 
    bars = barssince(cond == true)
    10 <= bars and bars <= 30

helper3function(_source, _var3) => not na(pivotlow(_source, 3, 3)) and _source[3] < (_var3 - external_source[3]) 

helper2function(_source, _var1, _var2, _var3) => _source[3] - _var1 > valuewhen(helper3function(_source, _var2), _source[3], _var3) and helper4function(helper3function(_source, _var2)[_var3])

helper1function(_source, _var2, _var3) => low[3] <= valuewhen(helper3function(_source, _var2), low[3], _var3)

function(_source, _var1, _var2, _var3) => helper1function(_source, _var2, _var3) and helper2function(_source, _var1, _var2, _var3) and helper3function(_source, _var2)
```

Comment: Please also add your function.

Comment: The function itself is very complicated and it is composed of other functions. I tried to simplify things. What are you thinking might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function's execution most probably depends on it building its history of past values for the series it is referencing, which cannot happen when it is called from within a `for` loop.

The same problem would occur if you were trying to call `ema()` from within a loop, with a different `length=` argument on each iteration of the loop. Because all the different calls would be happening in the `for` loop, Pine's runtime could not build the bar-by-bar trail of past values and calculations required to calculate the function on a new bar for each instance of calls to `ema()`.

For that to work, the runtime would have to spawn a new runtime environment for each loop iteration, which can't happen.

The usrman has a brief discussion of the issue at the end of [this section](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html?highlight=loop#for-statement).

Comment: Interesting. I added the function that I am trying to run. Could you have a quick look to see if you find something that might indicate a problem with the history of the series? I was thinking the problem might the series variable external_source[3] that I am using, however the study is run with argument max_bars_back=800, making sure that this value can be calculated.

Comment: The use of `barssince()` and `valuewhen()` is the cause. The whole thing is sorta related to this issue: [Why do some functions and built-ins evaluate incorrectly in if or ternary (?) blocks?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-functions-and-built-ins-evaluate-incorrectly-in-if-or-ternary--blocks). Same root cause, but different impact. As coders we're not aware of it, but in order to evaluate correctly, each of the instances where those functions are called would need a history trail of its own to evaluate correctly, which can't happen in `for` loops.